# Why does the set of rational numbers have no interior point?

Tags: real-analysis

If it is right, it is equal to

1. 'Every rational number has no neighborhood with only rational numbers'
2. 'Every rational number's neighborhood has infinitely many irrational numbers'

Comment: So have you thought about that? What does 1. mean?

Comment: 1 mean , if one's neighborhood has rational number , then it is a internal point.

Comment: Is 1. really an exact quote of the question? I assume the question is: "Is it true that every rational number has a neighbourhood which does not contain any other rational numbers"

Comment: have changed my contoent of 1.

Comment: Given any rational number, you cannot find a neighborhood consists solely of rational numbers. This is not possible because there are not enough rational numbers. There are countable many rational numbers but every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ contains some open interval which in terms contains uncountable many points.

Comment: @achille I don't like that - you are essentially assuming what you have to prove. All you need to establish is that if $r$ is rational, and $\epsilon>0$, then you can find an irrational number in $(r-\epsilon,r+\epsilon)$. Hmmm. Maybe not, because 2. needs something more ...

Comment: @almagest find an irrational number or find infinite ?

Comment: @almagest part 1. is about "neighborhood $\color{red}{\text{only}}$ have rational numbers", the argument I've is essentially a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Hunting has given you an elegant solution to both parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of open and closed are relative. A set $A$ can be open relative to $B$ even when it is not open relative to $C$.

Consider the neighborhood of $p\in\mathbb{Q}$ relative to $\mathbb{Q}$ i.e. the set $\{x\mid x\in \mathbb{Q} \text{ and } |x-p|<\varepsilon \}$. Consider the set of all rationals between $0$ and $1$(excluding $0$ and $1$) you can verify that it is open relative to $\mathbb{Q}$ (but not open relative to $\mathbb{R}$). So the statement $p$ is never an interior point is generally not true.

But if you want to consider  openness with respect to $\mathbb{R}$, we can use the result that says between any two rational numbers, there is an irrational number to prove that $p$ can never be an interior point of a set containing only rationals.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x$ be a rational number. Then $(x+\frac{\sqrt {2}}{n})$ is a sequence of irrational numbers converging to $x$.

Comment: how about all neighborhood of x?

Comment: it is still hard to translate huning's answer to a formal solution to both part.